# HTML form parameter are all null

Tags: java, html

I have to create a form for update some user profile data. I develop this html form but when I submit and I try to get request parameters they all result null.

The form is filled with actual data and then you can modify them refilling with the new one.

Thanks

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../CSS/style.css" th:href="@{.../CSS/style.css}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/signup.js" th:src="@{/js/signup.js}" defer> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/updateProfile.js" th:src="@{/js/updateProfile.js}" defer> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  th:src="@{/js/loadimage.js}" defer ></script> <!--defer fa eseguire js dopo il parsing di html-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Profilo Utente</h1>
        <div class="form">
            <form action="updateprofile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return formValidation()">
                <p>
                    <label for="username">Username: </label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" th:attr="value=${session.user.username}" required/><br>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="email">Mail: </label><br>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" th:attr="value=${session.user.email}" required/><br>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password">Password: </label><br>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"
                           pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"
                           title="Deve contenere almeno 8 caratteri di cui un numero, una lettera maiuscola e una lettera minuscola." /><br>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label id="text-password-confirm" for="password-confirm">Reinserisci password: </label><br>
                    <input type="password" id="password-confirm"  />
                </p>
                <p id="password-message" class="error-message"></p>
                <p>
                    Tipo di utente:<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="usertype" id="manager" value="manager" th:checked="${session.user.isManager!=null && session.user.isManager}" required/>
                    <label for="manager">Manager</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="usertype" id="worker" value="worker" th:checked="${session.user.isManager!= null && !session.user.isManager}" checked required/>
                    <label for="worker">Worker</label><br>
                </p>
                <div id="worker-data">
                    <p>
                        <label for="exp">Exp level:</label><br>
                        <select name="exp" id="exp">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Exp level</option>
                            <option value="LOW" th:selected="${session.user.exp == 'LOW'}">LOW</option>
                            <option value="MEDIUM" th:selected="${session.user.exp == 'MEDIUM'}">MEDIUM</option>
                            <option value="HIGH" th:selected="${session.user.exp == 'HIGH'}">HIGH</option>
                        </select><br>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="photo">Profile photo</label><br>
                    <div id="container"style="position: relative; width:300px;">
                        <canvas id="canvas_background" width="300px" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" accept="image/*"/><br>
                </div>
                <!-- TODO: Rivedere i messaggi di errore inseriti -->
                <span class="error-message" th:if="${session.signupfailed}">Salvataggio non riuscito</span>
                <p>
                    <input id="buttonModifica" type="button" value="Modifica" />
                    <input id="buttonAnnulla" type="reset" value="Annulla" />
                    <input id="buttonAggiorna" type="submit" value="Aggiorna" />
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is java code of the Update Profile controller

```
public class UpdateProfile extends AbstractServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("sessionUser");

        if (user != null && user.isValid()){
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            boolean isManager = request.getParameter("usertype").equals("manager");
            String photo;
            Level exp;
            if (isManager) {
                photo = null;
                exp = null;
            } else {
                photo = ImageEncoder.encodeImage(request.getPart("photo"));
                exp = Level.valueOf(request.getParameter("exp"));
            }

            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setPassword(password);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setIsManager(isManager);
            user.setPhoto(photo);
            user.setExp(exp);
        }
        try {
            UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO(connection);
            userDAO.updateProfile(user);
            success=true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }

}
```

Comment: share java code.

Comment: Thanks! I update the post with java code of the controller

Comment: include the javascript code. might help addressing your issue.

Comment: share formValidation() method code

Comment: I add all as answer, thanks

Comment: @Stefano Ferrario Is there proper servlet mapping in web.xml file? Does your code execute?

Comment: I have `@WebServlet(name = "UpdateProfile", urlPatterns = "/updateprofile")` above Update Profile code

Answer (score 0):

This are javascript code included in signup.jsp:

```
function formValidation(e) {
    var confirm_password = document.getElementById("password-confirm");

    if (comparePassword(confirm_password, "Le due password non coincidono") ) {
        /*e.preventDefault();
        window.history.back();*/
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


function comparePassword(inputtext, alertMsg){
    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    if(inputtext.value != password.value) {
        document.getElementById('password-message').innerText = alertMsg;
        inputtext.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is javascript code included in updateProfile.jsp:

```
var username = document.getElementById("username");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var password = document.getElementById("password");
var passwordConfirm = document.getElementById("password-confirm");
var radioWorker = document.getElementById("worker");
var radioManager = document.getElementById("manager");
var exp = document.getElementById("exp");
var photo = document.getElementById("photo");
var buttonModifica = document.getElementById("buttonModifica");
var buttonAnnulla = document.getElementById("buttonAnnulla");
var buttonAggiorna = document.getElementById("buttonAggiorna");

function init() {
    username.readOnly=true;
    email.readOnly=true;
    password.readOnly=true;
    passwordConfirm.hidden=true;
    radioManager.disabled=true;
    radioWorker.disabled=true;
    exp.disabled=true;
    photo.disabled=true;
    buttonAnnulla.hidden=true;
    buttonAggiorna.hidden=true;
    buttonModifica.addEventListener("click", abilitaModifica)
    password.addEventListener("change", verificaPassword)
}

function abilitaModifica() {
    email.readOnly=false;
    password.readOnly=false;
    exp.disabled=false;
    photo.disabled=false;
    buttonAnnulla.hidden=false;
    buttonAggiorna.hidden=false;
    buttonModifica.hidden=true;
}

function verificaPassword() {
    passwordConfirm.hidden=false;
}

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to update your servlet code with this one..

```
    @WebServlet(
      name = "UpdateProfile", 
      urlPatterns = {"/updateprofile"})
    public class UpdateProfile extends HttpServlet {

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            User user = (User) session.getAttribute("sessionUser");

            if (user != null && user.isValid()){
                String username = request.getParameter("username");
                String password = request.getParameter("password");
                String email = request.getParameter("email");
                boolean isManager = request.getParameter("usertype").equals("manager");
                String photo;
                Level exp;
                if (isManager) {
                    photo = null;
                    exp = null;
                } else {
                    photo = ImageEncoder.encodeImage(request.getPart("photo"));
                    exp = Level.valueOf(request.getParameter("exp"));
                }

                user.setUsername(username);
                user.setPassword(password);
                user.setEmail(email);
                user.setIsManager(isManager);
                user.setPhoto(photo);
                user.setExp(exp);
            }
            try {
                UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO(connection);
                userDAO.updateProfile(user);
                success=true;
            } catch (SQLException e) {

            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I already have `@WebServlet(name = "UpdateProfile", urlPatterns = "/updateprofile")` above `public class UpdateProfile extends HttpServlet {`.
Singup servlet already exist and is connected to the registration controller.

Comment: try to replace `urlPatterns = "/updateprofile"` with `urlPatterns = "/signup"` , because your form is sent to signup not updateprofile (in the action)

Comment: or you change in you jsp code and put  `action="updateprofile" ` and keep the actual mapping setting in the @WebServlet annotaion

Comment: I see you edited your post with action="updateprofile"  , does the problem always exists?

Comment: Sorry, I update the main answer with the right html code. In the action I have "update profile" but parameter always result null when processed by the controller

Comment: did you changed AbstractServlet to HttpServlet as well? (please don't edit the post at each time someone suggests a correction or everyone will get lost, tnak you)

Comment: No because AbstractServlet extends HttpServlet.

Comment: It contains `init()` function in order to avoid repetition. I have no problem with the other servlet...

Comment: ah right! well this is my last try, put `urlPatterns = {"/updateprofile"} ` (add this symboles { } )

Comment: Nothing, can't solve problem. Using debugger I can see the controller is correctly reached but all parameter passed in the request are null.

Comment: put the method of the form to `GET` instead of `POST` in your html code , only to check the values in the url from your browser, to see if it sends null values or they are filled with data (then make it back `POST` , this is only to check the parameters from the url)

Comment: I noticed that parameter are not null if I add `@MultipartConfig` tag... but I don't understand why...

Comment: because you put in your html code in the form tag `enctype="multipart/form-data"` , this annotation it is used to handle multipart/form-data requests

Comment: if you simply remove the enctype option from your html, it will works without adding the annotation